# TCP connection establishment related questions

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client, bind

I'm reading this code and have several questions about it:

1. When creating this TCP connection to host and port, it should return a file descriptor on success, and `-1` on error. But so far I can only see it returns `-1` when `connect (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0`, where did it show it returns a file descriptor on success?
2. `connect (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0` What does `<0` means here?
3. Which one is the function of reading the request? If there is none, could you provide me with some good code examples?

```
int tcpconnect (char *host, int port){
  struct hostent *h;
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  int s;
/* Get the address of the host at which to finger from the
* hostname. */
  h = gethostbyname (host);
  if (!h || h->h_length != sizeof (struct in_addr)) {
  fprintf (stderr, "%s: no such host\n", host);
  return -1;
}
  /* Create a TCP socket. */
  s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero (&sa, sizeof (sa));
  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_port = htons (0); /* tells OS to choose a port */
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY); /* tells OS to choose IP addr */
  
  if (bind (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0) {
    perror ("bind");
    close (s);
    return -1;
  }

  sa.sin_port = htons (port);
  sa.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr *) h->h_addr;
  
  
/* And connect to the server */
  if (connect (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0) {
    perror (host);
    close (s);
    return -1;
  }
return s;
}
```

Comment: 1. **it should return a file descriptor on success** - [`connect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) does not return a file descriptor.
2. The operator < is explained in any basic C++ book. 3. Too broad.

Comment: Regarding question 2: The meaning of the return value of [`connect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) can be easily looked up in the documentation of that function. Please note that [a certain amount of research is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/12149471) before asking a question on Stack Overflow. If something is unclear about the documentation, then feel free to ask about that.

Comment: Regarding question 1: The line `return s;` will return the file descriptor. The program will only reach that line if all function calls are successful.

Comment: Regarding question 3: The posted code of the function `tcpconnect` does not read anything from the file descriptor. This is probably done by the function calling `tcpconnect`. It will probably use the function [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [`recv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) on the returned file descriptor.

Answer (score 3):

> When creating this TCP connection to host and port, it should return a file descriptor on success, and `-1` on error. But so far I can only see it returns `-1` when `connect (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0`, where did it show it returns a file descriptor on success?

`s = socket(...)` creates the actual file descriptor, and then `return s;` returns that file descriptor to the caller of `tcpconnect()` if nothing goes wrong.  If anything does goes wrong, the code is releasing the file descriptor with `close(s)` and then returning `-1` to the caller.

> `connect (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof (sa)) < 0` What does `<0` means here?

`connect()` returns 0 on success, and negative on failure.  The code is simply checking if `connect()` fails. Same as it is doing with `bind()` (and *should* be doing with `socket()`).

> Which one is the function of reading the request?

There is nothing in the code shown that is reading a request. That happens outside of this code, after `tcpconnect()` returns a valid file descriptor to the caller.